# Etale morphisms to $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

What are all etale morphisms $X \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb Z$?

I know the characterization over $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ where $k$ is a field. These are disjoint union of finite separable field extensions.

So to answer my actual question, I have that every base change of $X$ to $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb Z_p$ is the disjoint union of finite separable field extensions.

How do I know what the actual $X$ is?

Comment: Is this idle curiosity, or do you need some aspect of the solution for something else? FWIW I think the answer is unlikely to be very nice - there's no separatedness requirement here, so you can get all sorts of funky gluings going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, weird morphisms can occur but if you restrict to connected finite étale covers $ X \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ then there is only the identity. In a more fancy way, the étale fundamental group of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial. If you drop out the connectedness then you get some copies of the identity. Its proof uses what you mentioned, first make some reduction modulo $p$ primes and then use the Hermite-Minkowski theorem to compute certain discriminants of number fields.